# low connectivity protocols or technologies

Tags: rest, tcp, server, protocols, connectivity

I'm trying to enhance a server-app-website architecture in reliability, another programmer has developed. 
At the moment, android smartphones start a tcp connection to a server component to exchange data. The server takes the data, writes them into a DB and another user can have a look on the data through a website. The problem is that the smartphones very regularly are in locations where connectivity is really bad. The consequence is that the smartphones lose the tcp connection and it's hard to reconnect. Now my question is, if there are any protocols that are so lightweight or accomodating concerning bad connectivity that the data exchange could work better or more reliable.

For example, I was thinking about replacing the raw TCP interface with a RESTful API, but I don't really know how well REST works in this scenario, as I don't have any experience in this area.

Maybe useful to know for answering this question: The server component is programmed in c#. The connecting components are android smartphones.

Please understand that I dont add some code to this question, because in my opinion its just a theoretically question.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

REST runs over HTTP which runs over TCP so it would have the same issues with connectivity.

Moving up the stack to the application you could perhaps think in terms of 'interference'. I quite often have to use technical stuff in remote areas with limited reception and it reminds of trying to communicate in a storm. If you think about it, if you're trying to get someone to do something in a storm where they can hardly hear you and the words get blown away (dropped signal), you don't read them the manual on how to fix something, you shout key words such as 'handle', 'pull', 'pull', 'PULL', 'ok'. So the information reaches them in small bursts you can repeat (pull, what? pull, eh? PULL! oh righto!)

Can you redesign the communications between the android app and the server so the server can recognise key 'words' with corresponding data and build up the request over a period of time? If you consider idempotency, each burst of data would not alter the request if it has already been received (pull, PULL!) and over time the android app could send/receive smaller chunks of the request. If the signal stays up, just keep sending. If it goes down, note which parts of the request haven't been sent and retry them when the signal comes back.

So you're sending the request jigsaw-style but the server knows how to reassemble the pieces in the right order. A STOP word at the end tells the server ok this request is complete, go work on it. Until that word arrives the server can store the incomplete request or discard it if no more data comes in.

If the server respond to the first request chunk with an id, the app can use the id to get the response and keep trying until the full response comes back, at which point the server can remove the response from its jigsaw cache. A fair amount of work though.